# How can I deal with the following : "error: the value of 'foo' is not usable in a constant expression."?

Tags: c++, yaml, eigen

I am using Yaml-cpp and Eigen in my small project.

For example, in `cfg_.yaml`

```
foo:
 bar: 15
```

In `constants.h`

```
#pragma once
#include "yaml-cpp/yaml.h"
#include <iostream>
#ifndef DO_FORWARD_GRADIENT_constexprANTS_H
#define DO_FORWARD_GRADIENT_constexprANTS_H
const std::string yaml_path = "${MYWORKSPACE}/cfg_.yaml";
YAML::Node cfg_ = YAML::LoadFile(yaml_path);
const int nq = cfg_["foo"]["bar"].as<int>();
#endif
```

In `main.cpp`

```
#include <Eigen.h>
#include <constants.h>

int main(){

Eigen::Matrix<double,nq,1> matrix_test;
matrix_test.setZero();

return 0;
}
```

But, the following error occurs:

> error: the value of 'nq' is not usable in a constant expression.

I figured out that this happens because the variable is not defined at compile time.

I want to use the yaml file to reduce the build time when changing the variables.

For example, I want to call the value of variable in `constants.h`  from the cfg.yaml.

How can I solve the error?

Comment: https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html?_sm_au_=isV4j6fS6HF4R3qPQ0WpHK6H8sjL6#TutorialMatrixDynamic

Comment: Even if it were possible to execute code during compilation, how could reading and parsing a YAML file every time you include "constants.h" reduce the build time? If you want to use a value from the file, write a small program that you run as a preprocessing step and generates a header with the constants you want.

Comment: C++ does not work this way. You must redesign how your program works.